# How to get message-body immediately after receive a HTTP header by using NSURLSession?

Tags: objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I want to use **NSURLSession** to receive a xml stream from server and display each xml immediately on the screen.

Here is my delegate code:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    // Enumerate each message-body.
    [data enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:^(const void * _Nonnull bytes, NSRange byteRange, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        // Convert message-body to xml string.
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes 
                                                    length:byteRange.length 
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Some code to display string.
            // ...
        });
    }];
}
```

This code works fine except one problem.
The problem is, sometimes when receiving stream, the **didReceiveData** doesn't be called immediately after **didReceiveResponse**, it sometimes receive more than one HTTP messages, and then call **didReceiveData** once to pass all messages which it just receive for me.

It can sometimes take a while for receiving multiple messages, and makes my application not able to display the xml in realtime.

Is there any configuration or property can make it call **didReceiveData** immediately? I read the document but find nothing useful.

Thanks a bunch.

### Update:

I tried to use **NSURLConnection** to do the same things, it runs perfectly without this problem.
Each **didReceiveData** is called behind **didReceiveResponse** immediately.

How can I make the **didReceiveData** of **NSURLSession** work just like **NSURLConnection**?

Comment: You mean you want to parse the xml data which is not completely received? How is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it well. Receiving XML stream means the server will send some information continually by tiny xml until cancel the task. So every message-body I received is complete xml.

Comment: If this is really a stream, why aren't you using NSURLSessionStreamTask?

Comment: NSURLSessionStreamTask is available on iOS9, but my application still have to support iOS 8 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, NSURLSession should send data as it receives it, but only after it receives a certain about of data, or after a period of time.

If you're trying to get individual chunks of data, you might instead consider sending them back from the server as a multipart response.  Each "part" would contain one of your messages, and you would get a new didReceiveResponse: callback between each one.

With that said, I'm not sure why NSURLConnection would behave differently.  They use a lot of the same code under the hood.  You might try filing a bug with Apple.